# Fixed length path between two nodes without knowing relationship type

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I want to find paths of a certain length between two nodes - but I don't know what relationships are involved. The tutorials and examples seems to require I know what type of relationship I want to use. E.g.

```
MATCH (martin { name:"Martin Sheen" })-[:ACTED_IN*1..3]-(x)
RETURN x
```

I want to ask the graph:

```
MATCH (martin { name:"Martin Sheen" })-[:3..3]-(x)
RETURN x
```

But Neo4J seems to hang (I have 600,000 nodes / 1.3m relationships). How can I find paths of a certain length between two nodes, in a performant manner, provided I have no information about the relationships?

Thanks

Comment: Your query doesn't even run :)

Comment: Silly me - tried to abstract my query for ease of reading but just got it plain wrong :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this is not surprising it is really slow. Since Neo4j2.0, the use of labels is almost mandatory for performance reasons.

So make sure to use labels + an indexed property at least for matching your first node.

Secondly, you can just match paths of fixed length without knowing the relationship types.

Assuming your "Martin Sheen" node has a label Person :

Create index for Person/name :

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name);
```

Match the person and the path

```
MATCH p=(martin:Person {name:"Martin Sheen"})-[*3..3]->(x)
RETURN p
```

Comment: Christophe is right. And you might have to do [*3..3] as [*3] is equal to [*1..3]

Comment: I can't use labels! There are 20 different relationship labels which are all possible - and growing. What helps is that I do know my start and end nodes, so my query that hangs looks like this:

START n=node(204558), m=node(382692) MATCH p=n-[*3..3]-m RETURN p LIMIT 1